# learning python with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, haar-classifier

When I am running face detection code, I am facing following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\python program\s1.py", line 11, in <module> ret, frame=cap.read()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Most probably when I am running code which have `ret, frame=cap.read()` this type of code I get error.

Please provide solution.

My full code is this code I have taken from website only:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('..\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

scaling_factor=0.5

while True:
    ret, frame=cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor, 
    interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    face_rects=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in face_rects:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0),3)

    cv2.imshow('Face Detector', frame)

    c=cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c==27:
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question and fix the indentation; it's unlikely to make a difference to your question, but it matters in Python, as you know... And to the site regulars here.

Comment: Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified your webcam works? The error tells `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` object hasn't been created as `cap` so that it's no `cap.read()` attribute. You may set webcam no. to `cv2.VideoCapture(-1)` for a trial if your webcam works with other application.

Apart from the error, the face_cascade data path should be specified in forward slash "`/`" as `(../haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml)` or double backslash "`\\` as `(..\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml)` in `Windows OS` instead of backslash "`\`".